# Using pip behind a PAC proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, python, pip

The proxy at my workplace is specified in a PAC file which is applied to browsers, but not the command prompt/PowerShell. This means I can't use pip, virtualenv or Python libraries that need web access like requests.

I've tried running pip with the `pip install package --proxy=username:password@address:port`, where `username:password` are my credentials and where `address:port` is the last line of the PAC file. However, this still returns `ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authorization Required',)`

Is there a way to directly use the PAC file as the proxy, or something similar?

Comment: I believe the command should be `pip install package --proxy http://username:password@address:port`